# I am trying to print the StringBuffer.toString() but its not working

Tags: java, json, eclipse, httpurlconnection, bufferedreader

I am making an http request and getting the json data from an API. I try to print the contents that I received but its not printing anything there are no errors either I cant seem to find the reason

This is for an API project

```
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Main
{
    private static HttpURLConnection connection;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        BufferedReader reader;
        String line;
        StringBuffer responseContent = new StringBuffer();

        // Method 1 java.net.HttpURLConnection
        try 
        {
            URL url = new URL("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums");
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // Request Setup
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
            connection.setReadTimeout(5000);

            int status = connection.getResponseCode();
            System.out.println(status);

            if(status > 299)
            {
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getErrorStream()));
                while((line = reader.readLine())!= null)
                {
                    responseContent.append(line);
                }
                reader.close();
            }
            else
            {
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    responseContent.append(line);
                }
                reader.close();
                System.out.println("In else.");
            }

            System.out.println(responseContent.toString());

        } 
        catch(MalformedURLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally 
        {
            connection.disconnect();
        }


    }

}
```

I am trying to get the whole https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums that you would normally see when you search this in your browser. 
But nothing is printing and there are no errors.
I am new to API and http stuff so Please explain in detail if its complicated

Comment: Are you sure you are getting a 200 response?

Comment: Yes I print the "status" it says 200. It even goes into the else part but idk what happens after that

Comment: does the code exit itself or does it run forever?

Comment: It exits @user8810865

Comment: Are you sure that your `reader` has content?

Comment: Yes it does....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran your code as is, and this is what it printed:

```
200
In else.
[  {    "userId": 1,    "id": 1,    "title": "quidem molestiae enim"  },  {    "userId": 1,    "id": 2,    "title": "sunt qui excepturi placeat culpa"  },  {    "userId": 1,    "id": 3,    "title": "omnis laborum odio"  },  {    "userId": 1,    "id": 4,    "title": "non esse culpa molestiae omnis sed optio"  },  {    "userId": 1,    "id": 5,    "title": "eaque aut omnis a"  },  {    "userId": 1,    "id": 6,    "title": "natus impedit quibusdam illo est"  },  {    "userId": 1,    "id": 7,    "title": "quibusdam autem aliquid et et quia"  },  {    "userId": 1,    "id": 8,    "title": "qui fuga est a eum"  },  {    "userId": 1,    "id": 9,    "title": "saepe unde necessitatibus rem"  },  {    "userId": 1,    "id": 10,    "title": "distinctio laborum qui"  },  {    "userId": 2,    "id": 11,    "title": "quam nostrum impedit mollitia quod et dolor"  },  {    "userId": 2,    "id": 12,    "title": "consequatur autem doloribus natus consectetur"  },  {    "userId": 2,    "id": 13,    "title": "ab rerum non rerum consequatur ut ea unde"  },  {    "userId": 2,    "id": 14,    "title": "ducimus molestias eos animi atque nihil"  },  {    "userId": 2,    "id": 15,    "title": "ut pariatur rerum ipsum natus repellendus praesentium"  },  {    "userId": 2,    "id": 16,    "title": "voluptatem aut maxime inventore autem magnam atque repellat"  },  {    "userId": 2,    "id": 17,    "title": "aut minima voluptatem ut velit"  },  {    "userId": 2,    "id": 18,    "title": "nesciunt quia et doloremque"  },  {    "userId": 2,    "id": 19,    "title": "velit pariatur quaerat similique libero omnis quia"  },  {    "userId": 2,    "id": 20,    "title": "voluptas rerum iure ut enim"  },  {    "userId": 3,    "id": 21,    "title": "repudiandae voluptatem optio est consequatur rem in temporibus et"  },  {    "userId": 3,    "id": 22,    "title": "et rem non provident vel ut"  },  {    "userId": 3,    "id": 23,    "title": "incidunt quisquam hic adipisci sequi"  },  {    "userId": 3,    "id": 24,    "title": "dolores ut et facere placeat"  },  {    "userId": 3,    "id": 25,    "title": "vero maxime id possimus sunt neque et consequatur"  },  {    "userId": 3,    "id": 26,    "title": "quibusdam saepe ipsa vel harum"  },  {    "userId": 3,    "id": 27,    "title": "id non nostrum expedita"  },  {    "userId": 3,    "id": 28,    "title": "omnis neque exercitationem sed dolor atque maxime aut cum"  },  {    "userId": 3,    "id": 29,    "title": "inventore ut quasi magnam itaque est fugit"  },  {    "userId": 3,    "id": 30,    "title": "tempora assumenda et similique odit distinctio error"  },  {    "userId": 4,    "id": 31,    "title": "adipisci laborum fuga laboriosam"  },  {    "userId": 4,    "id": 32,    "title": "reiciendis dolores a ut qui debitis non quo labore"  },  {    "userId": 4,    "id": 33,    "title": "iste eos nostrum"  },  {    "userId": 4,    "id": 34,    "title": "cumque voluptatibus rerum architecto blanditiis"  },  {    "userId": 4,    "id": 35,    "title": "et impedit nisi quae magni necessitatibus sed aut pariatur"  },  {    "userId": 4,    "id": 36,    "title": "nihil cupiditate voluptate neque"  },  {    "userId": 4,    "id": 37,    "title": "est placeat dicta ut nisi rerum iste"  },  {    "userId": 4,    "id": 38,    "title": "unde a sequi id"  },  {    "userId": 4,    "id": 39,    "title": "ratione porro illum labore eum aperiam sed"  },  {    "userId": 4,    "id": 40,    "title": "voluptas neque et sint aut quo odit"  },  {    "userId": 5,    "id": 41,    "title": "ea voluptates maiores eos accusantium officiis tempore mollitia consequatur"  },  {    "userId": 5,    "id": 42,    "title": "tenetur explicabo ea"  },  {    "userId": 5,    "id": 43,    "title": "aperiam doloremque nihil"  },  {    "userId": 5,    "id": 44,    "title": "sapiente cum numquam officia consequatur vel natus quos suscipit"  },  {    "userId": 5,    "id": 45,    "title": "tenetur quos ea unde est enim corrupti qui"  },  {    "userId": 5,    "id": 46,    "title": "molestiae voluptate non"  },  {    "userId": 5,    "id": 47,    "title": "temporibus molestiae aut"  },  {    "userId": 5,    "id": 48,    "title": "modi consequatur culpa aut quam soluta alias perspiciatis laudantium"  },  {    "userId": 5,    "id": 49,    "title": "ut aut vero repudiandae voluptas ullam voluptas at consequatur"  },  {    "userId": 5,    "id": 50,    "title": "sed qui sed quas sit ducimus dolor"  },  {    "userId": 6,    "id": 51,    "title": "odit laboriosam sint quia cupiditate animi quis"  },  {    "userId": 6,    "id": 52,    "title": "necessitatibus quas et sunt at voluptatem"  },  {    "userId": 6,    "id": 53,    "title": "est vel sequi voluptatem nemo quam molestiae modi enim"  },  {    "userId": 6,    "id": 54,    "title": "aut non illo amet perferendis"  },  {    "userId": 6,    "id": 55,    "title": "qui culpa itaque omnis in nesciunt architecto error"  },  {    "userId": 6,    "id": 56,    "title": "omnis qui maiores tempora officiis omnis rerum sed repellat"  },  {    "userId": 6,    "id": 57,    "title": "libero excepturi voluptatem est architecto quae voluptatum officia tempora"  },  {    "userId": 6,    "id": 58,    "title": "nulla illo consequatur aspernatur veritatis aut error delectus et"  },  {    "userId": 6,    "id": 59,    "title": "eligendi similique provident nihil"  },  {    "userId": 6,    "id": 60,    "title": "omnis mollitia sunt aliquid eum consequatur fugit minus laudantium"  },  {    "userId": 7,    "id": 61,    "title": "delectus iusto et"  },  {    "userId": 7,    "id": 62,    "title": "eos ea non recusandae iste ut quasi"  },  {    "userId": 7,    "id": 63,    "title": "velit est quam"  },  {    "userId": 7,    "id": 64,    "title": "autem voluptatem amet iure quae"  },  {    "userId": 7,    "id": 65,    "title": "voluptates delectus iure iste qui"  },  {    "userId": 7,    "id": 66,    "title": "velit sed quia dolor dolores delectus"  },  {    "userId": 7,    "id": 67,    "title": "ad voluptas nostrum et nihil"  },  {    "userId": 7,    "id": 68,    "title": "qui quasi nihil aut voluptatum sit dolore minima"  },  {    "userId": 7,    "id": 69,    "title": "qui aut est"  },  {    "userId": 7,    "id": 70,    "title": "et deleniti unde"  },  {    "userId": 8,    "id": 71,    "title": "et vel corporis"  },  {    "userId": 8,    "id": 72,    "title": "unde exercitationem ut"  },  {    "userId": 8,    "id": 73,    "title": "quos omnis officia"  },  {    "userId": 8,    "id": 74,    "title": "quia est eius vitae dolor"  },  {    "userId": 8,    "id": 75,    "title": "aut quia expedita non"  },  {    "userId": 8,    "id": 76,    "title": "dolorem magnam facere itaque ut reprehenderit tenetur corrupti"  },  {    "userId": 8,    "id": 77,    "title": "cupiditate sapiente maiores iusto ducimus cum excepturi veritatis quia"  },  {    "userId": 8,    "id": 78,    "title": "est minima eius possimus ea ratione velit et"  },  {    "userId": 8,    "id": 79,    "title": "ipsa quae voluptas natus ut suscipit soluta quia quidem"  },  {    "userId": 8,    "id": 80,    "title": "id nihil reprehenderit"  },  {    "userId": 9,    "id": 81,    "title": "quibusdam sapiente et"  },  {    "userId": 9,    "id": 82,    "title": "recusandae consequatur vel amet unde"  },  {    "userId": 9,    "id": 83,    "title": "aperiam odio fugiat"  },  {    "userId": 9,    "id": 84,    "title": "est et at eos expedita"  },  {    "userId": 9,    "id": 85,    "title": "qui voluptatem consequatur aut ab quis temporibus praesentium"  },  {    "userId": 9,    "id": 86,    "title": "eligendi mollitia alias aspernatur vel ut iusto"  },  {    "userId": 9,    "id": 87,    "title": "aut aut architecto"  },  {    "userId": 9,    "id": 88,    "title": "quas perspiciatis optio"  },  {    "userId": 9,    "id": 89,    "title": "sit optio id voluptatem est eum et"  },  {    "userId": 9,    "id": 90,    "title": "est vel dignissimos"  },  {    "userId": 10,    "id": 91,    "title": "repellendus praesentium debitis officiis"  },  {    "userId": 10,    "id": 92,    "title": "incidunt et et eligendi assumenda soluta quia recusandae"  },  {    "userId": 10,    "id": 93,    "title": "nisi qui dolores perspiciatis"  },  {    "userId": 10,    "id": 94,    "title": "quisquam a dolores et earum vitae"  },  {    "userId": 10,    "id": 95,    "title": "consectetur vel rerum qui aperiam modi eos aspernatur ipsa"  },  {    "userId": 10,    "id": 96,    "title": "unde et ut molestiae est molestias voluptatem sint"  },  {    "userId": 10,    "id": 97,    "title": "est quod aut"  },  {    "userId": 10,    "id": 98,    "title": "omnis quia possimus nesciunt deleniti assumenda sed autem"  },  {    "userId": 10,    "id": 99,    "title": "consectetur ut id impedit dolores sit ad ex aut"  },  {    "userId": 10,    "id": 100,    "title": "enim repellat iste"  }]
```

So, your code is working, it is generating the GET request, getting the data, and it's printing it out.  Maybe you have an issue with your console and/or however you're reading the console output.

Comment: Me too. Got the same result. I would just like to point out that MalformedURLException is extended class of IOException so you should catch IOException first.

Comment: Ok will do, But how do i fix the issue on my device.

Comment: When I put ioexception before it says that malformedexception has already been handled so i guess i dont need the malformed block

Comment: @KhizarMuhammad you're right, the order of catch blocks is fine.

Comment: @KhizarMuhammad what IDE are you using? That could cause the problem.

Comment: I am using eclipse java